# Some 'hidden' errors within array location (possibly)

Tags: java, arrays

I am tasked with making a program for this lab assignment. There's just something wrong but there is no syntax error. Previously, it'd give me an error code if I immediately put the correct employee ID, but now regardless of whether it's true or not, it keeps giving me error in that particular line.

I tried almost everything. I tried deleting the check ID and immediately head to find the hours and so on. I tried several things to unbug my codes but the problem persists. I suspect the problem is either on check ID or the array location. I tried rereading it several times but no matter what it seems fine to me.

```
package lab09q2;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[]args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        Payroll p = new Payroll ();

        System.out.print("Enter the employee ID: ");
        int ID = input.nextInt();

        p.checkID(ID);
        p.setHours();
        p.setPayRate();
        p.getWages();

    }

}
```

Logic:

```
package lab09q2;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;

public class Payroll {

    //Variables
    int[] employeeID = {5658845, 4520125, 789122, 8777541, 8451277, 1302850, 7580489};
    int[]hour = new int[7];
    double[] hourRate = new double[7];
    double[] grossWage = new double[7];
    private int id, location, hours, temp;
    private double payRate, temp1;

    public void checkID(int ID) {
        boolean met = false;
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        while (met == false) {
            for (int i = 0; i < employeeID.length; i++) {
                if (ID == employeeID[i]) {
                    met = true;
                    id = ID;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if (met == false) {
                System.out.println("ID does not match. Please try again.");
                System.out.print("Enter employee's ID: ");
                ID = input.nextInt();
            }
        }

    }

    public void setHours () {

        Scanner input1 = new Scanner (System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < employeeID.length; i++) {
            if (id == employeeID[i]) {
                location = employeeID[i];
                break;
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Enter the number of hours this employee work: ");
        temp = input1.nextInt();
        boolean test1 = false;
        while(test1 == false) {
            if(temp < 0) {
                System.out.print("Enter a positive value only: ");
                temp = input1.nextInt();
            }
            else {
                test1 = true;
            }
        }

        hour[location] = temp;

    }

    public void setPayRate () {

        Scanner input2 = new Scanner (System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < employeeID.length; i++) {
            if (id == employeeID[i]) {
                location = employeeID[i];
                break;
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Enter the hourly rate for this employee: ");

        temp1 = input2.nextInt();
        boolean test1 = false;
        while(test1 == false) {
            if(temp1 < 6.0) {
                System.out.print("Enter a value greater than $6.0: ");
                temp1 = input2.nextInt();
            }
            else {
                test1 = true;
            }
        }

        hourRate[location] = temp1;

    }

    public void getWages () {

        for (int i = 0; i < employeeID.length; i++) {
            if (id == employeeID[i]) {
                location = employeeID[i];
                break;
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }

        grossWage[location] = hourRate[location] * hour[location];

        System.out.printf("Employee #%d's salary is %.2f", employeeID[location], grossWage[location]);

    }

}
```

How the program should work is that I will enter the ID and the program will check it first. If it exists in the database, then it's fine and will proceed to the next step. Otherwise it will keep asking until the user's input match to one of those inside the employeeID array.

Then it will ask for the number of hours that employee has done. Verification is done to make sure the user does not enter a negative value. This value will be stored into the hour array with the location consistent to the employee's id location.

Then it will ask for the hourly rate. Verification for value less than 6. The same thing applies for this one: the value will be stored to hourrate array.

Finally that getWages method will simply try to pull the value from the array and calculate the wage which will be stored to the grossWage array. Then it display it.

Comment: Can you make the question title a bit more descriptive of the problem?

Comment: Also can you describe *what* exactly is wrong?  What output do you see, and what do you want to see instead?

Comment: @zengr Does that help?

Comment: "now regardless of whether it's true or not, it keeps giving me error in that particular line." What error code, on which line?

Comment: @markspace The output is just plain error in the last line of setHours method (hour[location] = temp;)

Comment: But what is the error message? share the plain text output you see.

Comment: Your 'location' is employeeId, it probably should be 'i' instead - now it is probably array index out of bounds

Comment: @zengr 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5658845
 at lab09q2.Payroll.setHours(Payroll.java:68)
 at lab09q2.Main.main(Main.java:17)

Comment: @kacperWolkowski Holy crap. Hang on. If that were  the case I'd die of shame honestly.. Wait..

Edit: Yep. That's the problem. I don't know how to thank you. I literally spent 30 mins+ getting frustrated and the problem is only that clumsy mistake. Thanks a lot. You saved me.

Comment: Voting to close due to the issue being a typographical error.